# "Run-Time Check Failure #0" error when casting glGenBuffers()

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>
#define GLEW_STATIC

int main(){
    glewInit();
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    //GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr); fs
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
    GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");


    float vertices[] = {
     0.0f,  0.5f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
     0.5f, -0.5f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y)
    -0.5f, -0.5f  // Vertex 3 (X, Y)
    };
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_FALSE);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Hi I'm just a clueless programmer, this is my issue, when I compile this I get

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

This code is from http://open.gl/context

I know it's some sort of initialization issue but I'm simply too retarded to understand what's going on. Could someone please explain to me what I did wrong and what I'm meant to do instead?

EDIT: Code fixing progress 
(Solution to last problem: Make `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);` first, then call `glewInit();`  )

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>
#define GLEW_STATIC

int main(){

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    //GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr); fs

    typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
    GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");



    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    glewInit();


    GLuint vertexBuffer;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);

    float vertices[] = {
     0.0f,  0.5f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
     0.5f, -0.5f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y)
    -0.5f, -0.5f  // Vertex 3 (X, Y)
    };


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);


    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);



    //glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_FALSE);


    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Current error: First-chance exception at 0x00000000  Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

RIGHT! Final progress report:
Turns out, GLEW does the typedef thing for you ( `//typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
    //GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");`
so remove this, I was basically redefining the crap that had already been defined, which is dumb. OK LESSON LEARNED, read the documentation from the API you're using before you blindly follow tutorials

FINAL CODE IMPROVEMENT FROM THIS

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>
#define GLEW_STATIC

int main(){
    //printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS))
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    //GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr); fs

    //typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
    //GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");

    printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS));

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    glewInit();


    GLuint vertexBuffer;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);

    float vertices[] = {
     0.0f,  0.5f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
     0.5f, -0.5f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y)
    -0.5f, -0.5f  // Vertex 3 (X, Y)
    };


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);


    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);



    //glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_FALSE);


    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: You called `glewInit` too early. It must be called when GL context is already active - after `glfwMakeContextCurrent`. Also, remove two lines after this call - you messing with manual function pointer addresses and GLEW at the same time, which is not a good thing.

Comment: I did as you said, and now it's giving me "First-chance exception at 0x00000000" Instead.

Comment: Add edited code to question. Also, are you sure your GL implementation have `glGenBuffers`? What is `printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS))`? (this should be after GL initialisaion, of course)

Comment: It should since it is mentioned in the tutorial and defined under the typedef  `typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
    GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");`

Comment: `typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*); GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");` remove it, as i've already said before. First, you getting address before context is made current - which is wrong. Second, there is just no need for that - you already have GLEW.

Comment: After chasing ghosts in my GLEW/GLFW application for 2 days, I am now close to remove GLFW entirely and do the windows stuff myself. Right after initializing glfw, glGetError() returns INVALID_ENUM error and it will not clear, no matter how often glGetError() is called. Maybe it is the binary package of GLFW I use, but maybe the quality of that library is not as good as one would think. I had to get past all above showed iterations, too. Now I am at a point where my patience with that library is running thin.